# Cypress function is not having refrence to first method that is written

Tags: cypress

I am trying to learn Cypress for my UI automation. The reference of the browser is not staying for second test, It is starting like fresh rowser instance for the second method I have , its not continuing from where it stoped for the first method.

Below is my code

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe("learn about Locators", ()=> {

it("visit the google page" , ()=> {
    cy.visit("https://www.google.com/");
    cy.get("input");
    cy.get('#APjFqb').type("test");
});

 it("can locate a button on the page ",()=> {

    cy.get('#APjFqb').type("test");
    //cy.visit("https://www.google.com/");
    //cy.get('#APjFqb').type("test").
    //cy.get('textarea[title="Search]');

 });
});
```

and My Test case looks like this in Cypress

[image]

If you see the first marked one is running fine and the second test case is starting as a fresh one. Not sure What I am missing here.

Here is my Cypress.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
e2e: {
  setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  // implement node event listeners here
  },
 //excludeSpecPattern: "**/2-advanced-examples/*"
   },
  });
```

Kindly advice If I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is supposed to work, tests should be *independent*, one test should not depend on another test. Cypress helps you accomplish writing *independent* tests by giving you a clean state of your application for each test.

If you want several tests to start from some common base-state, you can accomplish that in cypress using methods like `beforeEach`, explained here: https://filiphric.com/cypress-basics-before-beforeeach-after-aftereach